# How do I display styled error messages using pseudo css?

Tags: php, html, css

I've recently completed a simple login form with php and mysql.
Now I am heading onto the styling part which I am not too familiar with.

Login form code:

```
<div class="login-box-body">
<p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>

<form action="" method="post">
<div class="form-group has-feedback"><input class="form-control"
name="user_key" placeholder="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX" type="text" /></div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-8">
<div class="checkbox icheck"><label><input type="checkbox" /> Remember Me
</label></div></div>
<!-- /.col -->

<div class="col-xs-4"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"
name="submit" type="submit">Sign In</button></div>
<!-- /.col --></div>
</form>
```

Login form screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/afrajr

I was thinking maybe echoing it to display an outline around the box which is red when their is no valid key in the mysql table but i'm not sure how to.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? It looks like those are bootstrap classes. If yes, there is a section in the bootstrap docs that shows how to do a red outline for error states. [Look here](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation)

Comment: So basically put another class named `has-error` on your `form-group` div. And then for your error message, put the error message in a div with class `help-block` and put that div under the key textbox inside the `form-group`

Comment: If you know javascript, you can submit the form via ajax and return any error message in the json.  Then it's trivial to print specific message in the html.